# Chaning string in rows

Tags: r

I have a too big data frame

```
> dim(anno_maf)
[1] 2635299     132
>

> head(anno_maf[1:3,1:4])
                     Tumor_Sample_Barcode Chromosome Start_Position End_Position
1: LP2000107-DNA_A01_vs_LP2000102-DNA_A01       chr5      137536800    137536803
2: LP2000330-DNA_A01_vs_LP2000316-DNA_A01      chr11       64012229     64012231
3: LP2000330-DNA_A01_vs_LP2000316-DNA_A01      chr17       41720917     41720917
> 

> unique(anno_maf$Tumor_Sample_Barcode)
  [1] "LP2000107-DNA_A01_vs_LP2000102-DNA_A01" "LP2000330-DNA_A01_vs_LP2000316-DNA_A01" "LP2000332-DNA_A01_vs_LP2000323-DNA_A01"
  [4] "LP2000333-DNA_A01_vs_LP2000324-DNA_A01" "LP6005334-DNA_A02_vs_LP6005333-DNA_A02" "LP6005334-DNA_C01_vs_LP6005333-DNA_C01"
```

I want to remove everything thing from `vs` onward in `anno_maf$Tumor_Sample_Barcode`, for example leaving `LP2000107-DNA_A01` from `LP2000107-DNA_A01_vs_LP2000102-DNA_A01` but I don't know how to do that

Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sub()` is the way to go.

Your pattern is your regular expression: Check for "_vs_" followed by any character (provided with `.`) for an undefined length (provided with `*`).

```
my_text <- "LP2000107-DNA_A01_vs_LP2000102-DNA_A01"

sub(pattern = "_vs_.*",
    replacement = "",
    x = my_text)

[1] "LP2000107-DNA_A01"
```

Comment: Thank you, how I execute this on my data frame?

Comment: `your_df$your_col <- sub(your_pattern, replacement_string, your_df$your_col)`

Comment: For learners, it is always better to use parameters in the `name = value` format. I'd recommend `sub(pattern = your_pattern, replacement = replacement_string, x = your_df$your_col)`, so everything is explicit and the order of the parameters doesn't matter.

Comment: @Ram RS, I agree and that is why the `sub()` bit is written that way in the original answer. And actually I try to follow Hadley Wickham's style guide, in which the `name = value` format is used from the second parameter on. `sub()`, however, unconventionally (at least for me) takes `x` as the third argument, hence I used the `name = value` pairs for all of the arguments used. For those who are interested, here is the link for the tidyverse style guide: https://style.tidyverse.org

Comment: You're right, `sub`, `gsub`, `grep`, etc have weird parameter ordering and hence highly benefit from this format.